# Lyx cannot export/view as pdf, external program finished with error

Tags: pdftex, lyx

I get this message regardless of which program I select, there are no logs.

The external program
lualatex/pdflatex/xelatex
finished with an error. It is recommended you fix the cause of the external program's error (check the logs).

Comment: does this happen for every document you try? Please post an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), some more information about your setup.

Comment: are you able to compile the file and preview it ?

Comment: If you happen to be on Linux, start LyX from the command line (just type `lyx` in a terminal). Then check the messages there after you compile.